# add favicon with htaccess to a subdomain

Tags: html, css, http-headers, favicon

Without explicitly declaring `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">` in the head of my document, can I add a favicon to every page within a particular subdirectory? I thought I read once that it can be done by adding a one-line htaccess file to the directory which I want to display the facicon, but now I can't seem to find that documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no favicon is defined, generally the browser will query the root of the domain.

Ie. it will try www.example.com/favicon.ico

If you put the file there it will apply to the whole domain.

Comment: okay. it is a subdomain. it is not showing up as the favicon however. :/ thank you!

Comment: OK this could be a few different problems. First thing is first: open your server logs and check what URLs are being requested. You will one that contains favicon.ico (probably also generating a 404 right now). That will be where to put the icon.

Comment: I do have it working for the main directory of my site. It shoes up fine on every page. But the pages contained within this subdomain are where it's failing to show up.

Comment: Try putting it in the root of your subdomain then.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this

```
AddType image/x-icon .ico
```

Comment: Is that a line I can add to a text document and put into the subdomain? Thank you.